# Redirect all to ssl except admin panel

Tags: .htaccess

My website uses ssl, but in wp-admin I want to disable it. What I'am doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebiste.com/wp-admin/$1 [R,L]
```

My code redirects to http://www.mywebiste.com/wp-admin/wp-admin

**EDIT**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebiste.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now my code redirect https://www.mywebiste.com/wp-admin to http://www.mywebiste.com/wp-admin and it work's fine. But if I go to https://www.mywebiste.com/wp-admin/another-page it not working

Comment: if you use Cloudflare or any service like that you can set up a rule that disables the SLL over http://www.mywebiste.com/wp-admin/*

Comment: I don't use any of this services

Comment: Why would one want to _disable_ encryption for administrative stuff?!?

Comment: I am using custom module with api that connects to another server without posibility to activate ssl and browser blocks ajax connection.